# What is the suitable http content-type for consuming an asynchronous stream of data?

Tags: angular, spring-webflux, project-reactor, angular-httpclient

I am new to reactive programming. And my application uses the combination of Angular and Spring Webflux.

So I have a server Endpoint that produces the stream of Json_values with some delay 1sec.[Spring - webflux]

```
@CrossOrigin 
@GetMapping(value = "/flux" , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<ObjType> returnFlux()
{
    return Flux.just(Obj1, Obj2, Obj3,...)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
}
```

And my client ie. Angular Http is expected to log the response as soon as the chunk of data is available. [Angular]
my code looks like this

```
public getResponse()
{
    var _reqOptionsArgs= { headers: new HttpHeaders().set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' ) };

    var observable = this.httpClient.get<any>("http://localhost:8080/flux", _reqOptionsArgs);

    observable.subscribe(val => console.log(val),
                         err => console.error(err),
                         () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'));
}
```

Now I expect my method to log the json objects on console as soon as the flux emits them. But the browser throws an exception after waiting for 5 seconds when flux emits 5 values :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 8
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:9848:51)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3397:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:71849:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3396:60)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3174:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3471:34)
    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4609:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4646:21)
```

But when I trigger the localhost:8080/flux from Browser, it prints the response with as soon as the the object is emitted.

Maybe I am providing an wrong content-type for the response in httpClient in angular.
But at the same time, I am curious that how the browser responds to that chunk of data.

Comment: could you try with  {responseType: 'text'} in options

Comment: @kunalverma no luck! I've tried other content types as well. I feel most of these content types such as string,text,app/json.. expect the response as a whole. What I am looking for is the configuration that can allow http to consume the available response instead of waiting for whole response.

Comment: your content type is okay. HTTP protocol is a connection-less protocol. I would suggest websockets to achieve such functionality or polling if you want to stay with HTTP.

Comment: @RahulJaswal i am  telling about " responseType" ..the type of responcese you get from web api....

Comment: you're either making a standard http request (1 request, 1 response, no streams of data) or you're connecting to a websocket. the angular http client is for http requests ONLY. if you want to establish a websocket, you need to do something different. But it seems like you're unsure of what you're after yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular error you're getting is because *Streaming JSON* (`application/stream+json`) and plain old *JSON* (`application/json`) are two distinct content types. *Streaming JSON* differs in that it's a collection of individual JSON objects delimited by another value (usually a newline), and in itself, it's therefore not valid JSON.

Having said that, you're going to struggle using `HttpClient` for this - it's designed to read a full response and then close, whereas you're sending it a stream of JSON instead. (In essence, it's the wrong tool for the job.)

You almost certainly want to use `EventSource` instead, similar to:

```
var es = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/flux");
es.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
}
```

You can then call `JSON.parse()` or similar on `e.data`, and do what you like from there.

The only downside here is that `EventSource` doesn't let you set HTTP headers without a polyfill - but it looks like that may not be a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when your JSON isn't valid. Trying debugging as to what is the structure of JSON object arriving on your client side. Also try removing the http-headers and let the angular http-client handle them by itself